# Adding an convenience initializer extension for Objective-C class to be used in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use some code from [iOS-nRF-Toolbox](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Toolbox)

class ScannedPeripheral contains an initializer

```
+ (ScannedPeripheral*) initWithPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral rssi:(int)RSSI isPeripheralConnected:(BOOL)isConnected NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

I can call it in Swift like this

```
ScannedPeripheral.initWithPeripheral(peripheral, rssi: 0, isPeripheralConnected: true)
```

But it doesn't look nice. How does Apple do to adopt its Cocoa API?

I tried to mark the initializer with `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` and adds an Swift extension:

```
extension ScannedPeripheral {
    convenience init(peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: Int32, isPeripheralConnected: Bool) {
        ScannedPeripheral.__initWithPeripheral(peripheral, rssi: rssi, isPeripheralConnected: isPeripheralConnected);
    }
}
```

But now an error says `Self.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`.

Comment: Hi , it is a static method , use the following code it will work.

Comment: it is a static function( class function) , we cant use instance properties(self) in static functions.

Comment: OK it should be automatic convert Swift without function calles to named "init blah". The reason why it's not is because they are static methods, which are probably not very orthodox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is better to write subclass for ScannedPeripheral instead of extension because extensions may not support for initialisers and override methods.

eample

```
class SubClassScannedPeripheral: ScannedPeripheral {
  override class func initWithPeripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: Int32, isPeripheralConnected: Bool) -> ScannedPeripheral {
   return ScannedPeripheral.initWithPeripheral(peripheral, rssi: rssi, isPeripheralConnected: isPeripheralConnected);
}
}
```

Comment: How does Apple do with Cocoa API then? It doesn't look like sub-classing.

Comment: yes , they used new initialisers with convenience key word in that they may call the  initialisers of that class, but here you are try to overide the class function that is not an initialiser.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. But maybe your class doesn't give me what I want. For example, UIView initializer is `UIView(frame: cgrect)`. Not SubUIView(frame: cgrect).

Comment: yes , that is - (UIView *)initWithFrame(CGRect) frame {} it is initialzer , so it is possible to call like that

Comment: but our issue is , your initilizer function is static class function

Comment: your code is working if you add  super.init() call as very first line of your initialiser

Comment: Oh I see! That's unorthodox. Let me try some more.